# How to make the subcaption labeling appear on top left corner?

Tags: floats, labels

Currently, I am using this code

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters appropriately
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{font={bf,small},skip=0.25\baselineskip}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font={bf,small}, skip=1pt}


\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth, height=0.17\textheight, keepaspectratio]{H_beffect.png}%, 
\caption{}
\label{fig:halfsaturationeffect}
\end{subfigure}
%\quad
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth, height=0.17\textheight, keepaspectratio]{BIHSItransmission.png}
\caption{The effect of $\beta_b$ on $R_{ah}$}
\label{fig:rateoftransmission}
\end{subfigure}
%\hfill
\caption{Effect of half-saturation constant for birds with avian strain and transmission coefficient on the basic reproduction number.}
\label{fig:effectonR_0}
\end{figure}
```

How can I make the subfigures caption be located at top left corner of each subfigures instead of below the subfigures?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

like this?

[image]

on topic:

- just put `\caption{...}` before `includegraphics`
- to `\captionsetup[subfigure]{...}` add `singlelinecheck=false`

off-topic:

- in your code are missing `\begin{document}`, `end{document}` and package `graphicx`
- don't use `figure` option `[H]`, it can cause unpleasant document formatting. the option `[ht]` should be sufficient
- don't force images' widths to be larger than widths of `subfigure` environment (images will overlaps)

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters appropriately
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{font={bf,small},skip=0.25\baselineskip}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font={bf,small}, skip=1pt, singlelinecheck=false}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\linewidth}
\caption{}
\label{fig:halfsaturationeffect}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.17\textheight, keepaspectratio]{H_beffect.png}%,
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\linewidth}
\caption{The effect of $\beta_b$ on $R_{ah}$}
\label{fig:rateoftransmission}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.17\textheight, keepaspectratio]{BIHSItransmission.png}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Effect of half-saturation constant for birds with avian strain and transmission coefficient on the basic reproduction number.}
\label{fig:effectonR_0}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the caption overlap the subfigure, while being on the top left corner?

Comment: @samwolfe, do you mean that is wider than subfigure or that it is inside subfigure? Both is possible. Browse site for solution on similar question or ask new question.

Comment: I have [asked it here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/693703/how-to-overlap-subfigure-with-caption), please check it, if you have any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: @samwolfe, Celdor already provide a good answer on your question ...