# How to overlap subfigure with caption

Tags: graphics, floats, captions, subcaption, subfig

Consider the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[htpb]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{}
            \label{figa}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{}
            \label{figb}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}
\par\medskip
\caption{Example caption.}
\label{fig}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

How can I position the captions of the subfigures, (a) and (b), in any position overlapping the image? For example, how can I get

[image]

**Edit:** For example, using something like

```
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font={bf,small}, skip=-100pt, margin=0.1cm, singlelinecheck=false}
```

almost does the trick

[image]

but not quite. Putting `\caption` before `\includegraphics` also does not seem to help, as the caption moves to the back layer. Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately your posted code can't compile. Please add the missing lines. Nobody here likes to reengineer preambles. Thank you

Comment: @MS-SPO Thanks for pointing that out. Please see the edit. A potential solution without `tiks` would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621260/position-subcaption-within-subfigure-at-the-top-inset

Answer (score 3):

In those kind of scenarios, I think `tikz` provides good solutions, at least to start with. The only thing is in this case you have to split actions of a regular `\caption` because the latter cannot be used as a argument of `\node` (see section 7.3 of [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption)).

Below is one example. Referencing to each subfigure should work, as usually. Since you keep them on the same page, I just stuck `\captionlistentry`s to generate anchors, so that you can reference each subfigure. Then, `\captiontext*` is just to produce empty labels. This way there shouldn't be a problem to append more images.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcounter{subfig}


\begin{document}
\kant[1]

\begin{figure}[tbh]
  \setcounter{subfig}{0}
  \newcommand\typecap{\stepcounter{subfig}\captiontext*[\value{subfig}]{}}
  \captionsetup{position=bottom, skip=3pt}
  \centering
  \begin{subcaptiongroup}
    \captionlistentry{}\label{figa}   % Required to reference subfigures
    \captionlistentry{}\label{figb}
    \tikz[
      node distance=3pt,
      caption/.style={
        anchor=north west,
        font=\bfseries,
        outer sep=6pt,
      },
      relpos/.style={
        right=of #1.south east,
        anchor=south west,
      },
    ] {
      \node (A) {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
      \node (B) [relpos=A] {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}};
      \node (C) [relpos=B] {\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{example-image-b}};
      \node at (A.north west) [caption] {\typecap};
      \node at (B.north west) [caption] {\typecap};
      \node at (C.north west) [caption] {\typecap};
    }
  \end{subcaptiongroup}
  \caption{Example caption.}\label{fig}
\end{figure}

\kant[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is quite useful! It's a bit sad that I can't get away with my approach. Positioning `\caption` above `\includegraphics` seems to almost solve the issue, but the graphics still appear on the front layer, hiding the caption. Nonetheless, this is a great answer.

Comment: If I may ask, how would you use `minipage` or `\quad` to display the subfigures in multiple rows?

Comment: Also, is it possible to slightly push the caption to the right or further down, to adjust depending on the image? In my case I have a [framed plot](https://imgur.com/a/4ffWewa), so ideally I would like it to be positioned a bit more towards the center, so that the subcaption does not overlap the frame or one of the axes.

Comment: Perhaps remove `outer sep` or set it to 0pt, that is use `outer sep=0pt` to remove margins. The labels will stick to left-hand side upper corner. Then, you can append `xshift` and/or `yshift` to move labels around the default anchor.